# MYSQL TIMESTAMPDIFF() gives wrong value

Tags: mysql

I'm giving input to `TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,'29-10-2012','19-11-2012')` but I'm getting output as `504` but the value should be `510`.

The output is `510` because start value is `29/10/2012 05:13`.

Is there alternative to this function which gives Day,Hour,Minute,Second difference between two dates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You pass **DATE** values in TIMESTAMPDIFF function, all is correct -

- 3 days in october: 2012-10-29, 2012-10-30, 2012-10-31 = 3 * 24 = 72
- 18 days in november: 2012-11-01...2012-11-18 = 18 * 24 = 432

72 + 432 = 504

If you want to count hours, minutes or seconds, then you should pass two **DATETIME** values -

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,'2012-10-29 05:13:00','2012-11-19 00:00:00') hours;
+-------+
| hours |
+-------+
|   498 |
+-------+
```

Comment: :When you say end day is 19,it means 19/11/2011 12:00 PM.Am,i correct ?

Comment: It is '2012-11-19 00:00:00' which is '2012-11-19 12:00 AM'.